# RuntimeError: uvloop does not support Windows at the moment

Tags: python-poetry, langchain, uvloop

Following this:https://github.com/levalencia/langchainLuisValencia/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md#-common-tasks
On Windows.

Forked the repo, cloned it locally, created a conda environment, (Poetry was already installed), then installed all dependencies.

Error received:

```
• Installing xmltodict (0.13.0)
• Installing zstandard (0.21.0)

ChefBuildError

Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_wheel

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in
main()
File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
File "C:\Users\LUISVA1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn9w63h_u.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
File "C:\Users\LUISVA1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn9w63h_u.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "C:\Users\LUISVA1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn9w63h_u.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
File "C:\Users\LUISVA1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn9w63h_u.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 8, in
RuntimeError: uvloop does not support Windows at the moment

at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\Lib\site-packages\poetry\installation\chef.py:147 in _prepare
143│
144│ error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
145│
146│ if error is not None:
→ 147│ raise error from None
148│
149│ return path
150│
151│ def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:

Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with uvloop (0.17.0) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --use-pep517 "uvloop (==0.17.0)"'.
```

How can I fix this?

What do I need to do to be able to test locally? Before I start to contribute?